# How to turn off a playing audio file

Tags: python, audio, clock, alarm

So, I recently decided to give myself a simple project to test my python literacy. What I created was an alarm clock that asks for the time someone wishes to wake up, and at that time, it plays an mp3 file with VLC and will only turn off once the user has answered a randomly generated math problem. The problem is, I can't figure out how to make the alarm stop playing the alarm sound. I have tried using os.popen to give a killall VLC command but this failed to resolve the issue.

Here is the complete code:

```
#IMPORTS
import datetime
import time
import os
import sys
import random

#VARIABLES
alarm_HH = 00
alarm_MM = 00
number_a = random.randrange(0, 999, 2)
number_b = random.randrange(0, 999, 2)
command_alarm = 'open -a "VLC" /Users/AlexW/Documents/alarm.mp3'
command_VLC = 'open -a /Applications/VLC.app'
command_close = 'killall VLC'

#THE ACTUAL ALARM
def alarm_function():
    #GLOBALS
    global command_close
    global command_alarm
    global alarm_HH
    global alarm_MM
    global number_a
    global number_b
    while True:
        now = time.localtime()
        if now.tm_hour == int(alarm_HH) and now.tm_min == int(alarm_MM):
            os.popen(command_alarm)
            print ("---------------")
            print ("Solve this math problem to disable the alarm")
            print (number_a)
            print ("+")
            print (number_b)
            print ("---------------")
            answer = input("Enter Your Answer: ")
            if answer == number_a + number_b:
                os.popen(command_close)
                print ("---------------")
                print ("Alarm Disabled")
                alarm_sleep()
            else:
                print ("---------------")
                print("Try again")
        else:
            pass

#SET THE TIME FOR THE ALARM
def alarm_set():
    #GLOBALS
    global command_VLC
    global alarm_HH
    global alarm_MM
    print ("---------------")
    alarm_HH = input("What hour do you want to wake up? (24 hour format) ")
    print ("---------------")
    alarm_MM = input("How about the minute? ")
    print ("---------------")
    print ("Opening VLC Player")
    os.popen(command_VLC)
    print ("---------------")
    print ("Alarm Set")
    print ("---------------")
    print ("To disable the alarm, quit this program")
    alarm_function()

#COOLDOWN
#Used to prevent the alarm from going off twice once the question is completed
def alarm_sleep():
    time.sleep(60)
    alarm_function()

#STARTING SEQUENCE
print ("----------------")
print ("MATH ALARM CLOCK")
print ("----------------")
answer = input("Type <<1>> to start ")
if answer == 1:
    alarm_set()
else:
    alarm_set()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to execute the kill all command under sudo privileges. VLC has no native command line quit, so killing is the right way to close the process.

Comment: I tried this, it still doesn't work. "command_close = 'sudo killall VLC'"

Comment: can u su root and rerun the script without the sudo and see if that works? I'm not sure if the sudo in the close command prompts for password.